# How does this SQL syntax work? Multiple left join with single on

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I came across the T-SQL statement shown below and I don't know how joins are made for syntax like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) e2.[Id]
FROM [Sandbox].[dbo].[Employee] as e2
LEFT JOIN Employee AS e1 
LEFT JOIN Employee AS e3 ON e1.Id = e3.Id
```

Comment: The first left join looks like a cross join to me, as there is no `ON` condition.  I'm not sure if this would even run on SQL Server, or if it did, if the results would be what you want.

Comment: That query doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It is possible to "nest" joins, although it isn't done often as it can be a nightmare to follow the logic. But; in the snippet you have shown, it just does not look valid. Is there more to the query that you haven't included?

Comment: In SQL Server (and standard SQL), each `JOIN` (except `CROSS JOIN`) requires an `ON` clause.  hence, your query is not syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give a syntax error. Because in First Left Join there is no ON condition so it will not run. But you can use left join with single table on changing its alias according to some condition, it works fine. Could you please give some more clarification of your output.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at syntax at MSDN site: [FROM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), you will something like this:

```
<joined_table> ::=   
{  
    <table_source> <join_type> <table_source> ON <search_condition>   
    | <table_source> CROSS JOIN <table_source>   
    | left_table_source { CROSS | OUTER } APPLY right_table_source   
    | [ ( ] <joined_table> [ ) ]   
}  
<join_type> ::=   
    [ { INNER | { { LEFT | RIGHT | FULL } [ OUTER ] } } [ <join_hint> ] ]  
    JOIN
```

where you see (not so clearly :) ) that every `JOIN` **must have** `ON` clause, except `CROSS JOIN`.

There's one exception, when you are putting `JOIN` condition in `WHERE` clause, as following:

```
select * from t1, t2
where t1.id = t2.t1_id
```

Since I don't see any `WHERE` clause in your query, this query will not work, you'll get something like this:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near 'e1'.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest what you're showing isn't the complete statement (if it runs without error) and there's a later `ON` that you've ignored. Think of `JOIN` and `ON` the same way you would about opening and closing brackets. They have to match, and the rules for matching brackets/parentheses also work for working out which `JOIN` a particular `ON` clause relates to.

Here, you've shown us the `ON` clause that relates to the `JOIN` between `e1` and `e3`. There's another `ON` clause than then controls the `JOIN` between `e2` and `(e1 joined to e3)`.